# What classification algorithm select for text categorisation

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, classification

I have 5000 articles on the subject I need they all categorised and grabbed as plain text.

I need to train a model so it was classify to relate it to my topic or not.

If I got example form scikit-learn form 20newsgroups.
In example i have Pipeline with SGDClassifier:

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                 ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',
                                       alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5,  random_state=42)),])
```

and next i train my classifier send to it array of articles and array of categories but I have only one category and if i send array [1,1,1,1,1,1......1] it's have no effect.

What way to learn I should select in this case?
What classifier and how I need learn it and did I need other text normalisation or something else before train model

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with only one category? Classification is between two or more categories. E.g. spam/not spam, positive/negative review, sports/science/economy news...

Comment: for example:
I need get form news feed only sport news.
I have 5000 sport articles for learning.

Comment: You must have articles for the other categories you may find in your feeds in order to train the classifier to distinguish news against others. Make two classes, "news" and "other". Use your 5000 news article and 5000 articles for the other category.

Comment: You can also look at the http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html if you have data for only one class